# Are US patents protected by copyright or can I reproduce them on my website?

Tags: public-domain

Patents are a good source of accurate, or scientific information. They also have information about the inventor.  Are the patents in the public domain?  Can I reproduce them on my website?

Comment: Patents are not necessarily a good source of scientific information. There is no burden to prove a patented technology actually works. I’ve read many patents that are based on garbage science.

Comment: The point of the patent system is to introduce new knowledge into the body of freely available knowledge.  The quid pro quo in doing this is that the patentee gets a 20 year monopoly.  It would not make much sense that the patentee could hold a copyright on the description used to introduce that knowledge to the public.